# Getting error convert json to java object

Tags: java, json

My json is : `{"language":"English (US)","locale":"en_US","value":"aa"aa"}`. 
Getting error the json to java object for value , where value is : `"aa"aa"` .

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You input JSON is wrong. If the value contains `"` then you need to add escape sequence before the `"` like this:

```
{
   "language":"English (US)",
   "locale":"en_US",
   "value":"aa\"aa"
}
```